# RESTFUL API retrieving elements collection

Tags: json, rest, restful-url, restful-architecture

I am designing a RESTFUL API and I have a dude with one of my operations:

The client app needs to make a request to the server to retrieve a JSON with available questions to the user (based on certain restrictions).

The problem is that:

- Every user belongs to a client, meaning that client only will see questions that belongs to client's users.
- A priori, I don't know the id's of such questions.
- A user can need a question that other user already have.

I have thought of using: v1/questions/next/{numberOfQuestions}

The numberOfQuestions parameters would be optional (1 by default) and the client will be got in server.

Which approach would be the better one?

Thanks!

Comment: What does `v1/questions/next/{numberOfEvents}` have to do with clients and users?

Comment: Sorry, It has some mistake on the text. I am newbie in RESTFul design but as far as I know, every url must match with a specific resource. Isn't it? So, If I have 'v1/questions/next/34', if 2 users of differents clients make this request, the response will be different.

Comment: No, the response *must* be the same. The URL must be enough to identify the resource. What do you want to achive?

Comment: I want to retrieve a collection of availabe questions from server but depending on the user's client, the set of questions inserted in the JSON will be different. Doesn't matter that?

Comment: Can the client be part of the URL?

Comment: I think so. Are yo saying something like v1/clients/{clientId}/questions/next/{numberOfQuestions} ?

Comment: Yes, something like this. What does the `next` stand for?

Comment: OK. The operation must have a param (next) to indicate the number of questions the client needs to retrieve. So i have to differenciate between access to question with id=3 and get next 3 questions (next/3)

Comment: Does a request to this URL including the `next` part always return the *same* response?

Comment: No. Must be the next 'n' availables so will be changing...what do you think will be the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Get *all* questions for a user

```
GET /v1/clients/{clientId}/users/{userId}/questions
```

returns:

```
{"questions":
  [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "What is brown and barks?",
      "answered": false
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "What is brown and makes Moo?",
      "answered": false
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "What is brown and makes Meow?",
      "answered": true
    }
  ]
}
```

### Get only *unanswered* questions for a user

```
GET /v1/clients/{clientId}/users/{userId}/questions?answered=false
```

returns:

```
{"questions":
  [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "What is brown and barks?",
      "answered": false
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "What is brown and makes Moo?",
      "answered": false
    }
  ]
}
```

### Get only *one unanswered* question for a user

```
GET /v1/clients/{clientId}/users/{userId}/questions?answered=false&limit=1
```

returns:

```
{"questions":
  [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "What is brown and barks?",
      "answered": false
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Looks great! I think this will be a good approach for me. Really thanks!